# Jpa entity same record duplicated and making unique key violation

Tags: java, jpa, entity, constraintviolationexception

I am using Jpa, my website is shows a form in 3 steps, in every step i'm making `save()` in many steps :

- First `save()` will create a record `A` with a primary key `id` and another unique key `userId`, data as firstname and lastname
- Step 2 is where the user will enter his adress, then the same first `save()` is played

But I see an error :

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "userId" XXXX already exists
```

A `save()` is supposed to make an `update` if the record exists, but I noted that my `id` increments in every `save()` how to prevent this incrementation ?

here is my entity :

```
@Table(name = "user", schema = "salesforce", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "userId" }) })
```

public class Beneficiary implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

 @Column(name = "userID")
private String userId;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;
```

The service :

```
void save(List<User> users, String idDocument); // it can be same users with same idDocument
public Beneficiary save(Beneficiary newBeneficiary);
```

The repository

```
@Override
public User save(User newUser) {
    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(List<User> users, String idDocument) {
    users.forEach(newUser -> {
        newUser.setDocument(new Document());
        newUser.getDocument().setIDDocument(idDocument);
        save(newUser);
    });
}
```

In every step, the same `save()` is played but first i got the error saying that I'm trying to write a new ligne with the same UserId and it creates the duplication violation

This re-write is due to the fact that `Id` is incrementing ! why ?

Comment: I think, you are trying to save the detached User object, hibernate will try to save object, it is not aware that there is already a object with same `id`, hence it will issue the insert statement with `id`, you need to first fetch the object and then make changes to that.

Comment: Yes indeed @code_mechanic it means the fetch should be done before the save in my repository ? findAllById ?

Comment: Yes, but fetch by Id each user and then update its state with the properties of your detached object, updates are little hard with JPA.

Comment: `EntityManager.merge` makes it easy but sometimes thats not the option.

Comment: Although, you should fetch first and then update but your problem is different,  you have constraint on `userId`, so please check if that value is not repeating for every user, if you are adding new user using `save` method every time then your code is fine.